# Activate two "oneshot" services from one systemd timer so that they are started one after another

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I have two service oneshots:

- one that creates snapshots
- one that sends snapshots

The second one (send) should **always be executed after** the first one (create) is finished. Currently the services, which are of type `oneshot`, run at the same time.

The services are defined as follows (the exact used command from the following examples doesn't matter for this question, detailed requirements below the examples):

- Service to create snapshots (`pyznap.service`):

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Create ZFS snapshots
  Documentation=man:pyznap(1)
  Requires=local-fs.target
  After=local-fs.target

  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/pyznap snap
  ```
- Service to send snapshots (`pyznap-send.service`):

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Send ZFS snapshots
  Documentation=man:pyznap(1)
  Requires=local-fs.target network-online.target
  After=local-fs.target network-online.target pyznap.service

  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/pyznap send
  ```

Currently, they are triggered by individual (and independent) timers:

- The timer for the create snapshot (`pyznap.timer`):

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Run pyznap snap every 15 minutes

  [Timer]
  OnCalendar=*:0/15
  Persistent=true

  [Install]
  WantedBy=timers.target
  ```
- The timer for the send snapshot (`pyznap-send.timer`):

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Run pyznap send every 15 minutes

  [Timer]
  OnCalendar=*:0/15
  Persistent=true

  [Install]
  WantedBy=timers.target
  ```

---

Additional notes:

- The question is related to ["How do you configure multiple systemd services to use one timer?](https://serverfault.com/a/966588), but this solution still runs the services at the same time
- [As per `systemd` design](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html), only one service can be referenced by `Timer.Unit`.
- The units are separated due to different requirements:

  - only the "send" service needs network
  - the "create" service must run also without network
  - I am fine with skipping those services if requirements are not met
- The "send" service should run *immediately after* the previous "create" service.
- If there's only one timer:

  - the timer cannot activate only the send snapshot service as the create snapshot service needs also to run without network
  - but the timer could activate only the create snapshot service if there's a way to run the send snapshot service directly afterwards
- We don't know how long the first create snapshot service takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary question seems to be how to start a second `systemd` service immediately after a first one was successfully started. It doesn't state what to do in case the `pyznap.service` is finished but the `pyznap-send.service` lacks the network connection to actually send the snapshots, so I will assume that you don't intend a sophisticated retry-logic.

In that case, you may consider omitting the second service and adding an `ExecStartPost` line to the `pyznap.service` that calls `pyznap` with the `send` option:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/pyznap send
```

**Alternatively**, if you want to have slightly more of `systemd`'s control features, you could still define the `pyznap-send.service`, but activate it from the `pyznap.service` via an `ExecStartPost` statement:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/systemctl start pyznap-send.service
```

In that case, you will need to remove the `After=pyznap.service` statement in the `pyznap-send.service` file, since the `pyznap.service` may not yet be registered as "started" when the `ExecStartPost` line starting the `pyznap-send.service` is called.

Comment: I like this second approach with ExecStartPost! Didn't think of that. It still allows it to require on network-online.target and makes sure it at least tried to run the second oneshot.